# Can my dropdownlistbox on MVC fire an event so I can populate another?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a dropdownlistbox on my MVC web page. The dropdown allows me to select country name. When a user changes the country I would like another drop down to be populated with cities for that country.

Is this possible to do with MVC?  I am not sure if I should use javascript, AJAX, jquery or a combination of the two.

All help and advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like cascading drop down lists... check out http://netprogramminghelp.com/javascript/creating-developing-cascading-dropdownlist-using-ajaxjqueryjavascriptaspnet/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's ajax capabilities. When the 1st list changes ([`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)), send an ajax request to an MVC JSON action. When the request returns, you can use it to populate the next dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDropDown').live('change', function(){
});
```

You can also use Ajax calling a secondary page, where you populate and return one jSon serialized.

the other option is using AutoPostBack and OnSelectedIndexChanged (use this as [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22ASP%3aDROPDOWNLIST%22%29;k%28VS.HTMLDESIGNER.HTML%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-ASPX%29&rd=true))

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript >
    //Function for package binding on ddlindustry selected change index
    $("#ID_OF_THAT DDL").change(function () {

        var vv = $("#ID_OF_THAT DDL option:selected").val();
        if (vv >= 0) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '<%=Url.Action("ACTION", "CONTROLLER") %>',
                data: {
                    "VARIABLE_TO_PASS": $("#ID_OF_THAT DDL option:selected").val()
                }, //you can call public action from controller
                dataType: "text", //in data enter value which u have 2 pass must same as like control actioresult passing param
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: bindpackage
            })
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function bindpackage(result) {
        eval(result);
    }
```

After that in your controller :

```
public ActionResult Function123 (int VARIABLE_TO_PASS){

    RjsResult r = new RjsResult();

    ViewData["Name"] = function to get data;

    r.update("DIV_NAME","Name of the partial to update",ViewData, ControllerContext);

    return r;

}
```

Hope that helps :)